# Errors in file "magento_sample_data_for_1.9.1.0.sql"

Tags: magento-1.9, sample-data

In table `'eav_attribute'.'attribute_id' = 121` and `164` are missing.
Since many related tables have reference to them, I cannot import all the related data.

```
MySQL error #1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
 (`DB`.`catalog_product_entity_int`, CONSTRAINT `FK_CAT_PRD_ENTT_INT_ATTR_ID_EAV_ATTR_ATTR_ID`
 FOREIGN KEY (`attribute_id`) REFERENCES `eav_attribute` (`attribute_id`)
 ON DELETE CASCADE)
```

Could anyone just tell me what data to put into `'eav_attribute'.'attribute_id' = 121` and `164`?

(It has a few more bugs, but I managed to fix them)

Answer (score 2):

Sample data need to be installed [prior to Magento installation](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/installing-sample-data-archive-for-magento-ce). Not taking this into account might be the basic cause of all the problems you are experiencing.